# Convertir CSV en JSON multiarray con PowerShell

Tags: json, csv, powershell

Muy buenas!

Necestio crear un script en PowerShell que convierta un CSV en un fichero JSON.
La peculiaridad es que el JSON resultante necesito que sea multiarray con 2 niveles diferentes.

Os dejo el ejemplo de CSV de origen y el JSON resultante que tengo que conseguir:

[image: Ejemplo CSV]

Y aquí el JSON:

```
{
  "userone" : {
    "nombre" : "pablo",
    "activo": "si"
  },
  "usertwo" : {
    "nombre" : "maría",
    "activo": "no"
  }
}
```

¿Podrían ayudarme?
Mil gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomando el siguiente .CSV:

```
usuario, nombre, activo
userone, pablo, si
usertwo, maria, no
```

Uan posible solución es ejecutar lo siguiente:

```
$csvData | % { 
    New-Object psobject @{$_.usuario=@{'nombre'=$_.nombre; 'activo'=$_.activo}}
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

Que tiene por resultado lo siguiente:

```
[
  {
    "userone": {
      "nombre": "pablo",
      "activo": "si"
    }
  },
  {
    "usertwo": {
       "nombre": "maria",
       "activo": "no"
    }
  }
]
```

Lo único que veo es que agrega un par de corchetes adicionales para cada objeto... No se si eso interfiere con lo que necesitas.